# Do modems cache something?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, modem, browser-cache

I didn't know how to choose an appropriate clear title for it, cache requests, cache Domain Name Systems or... then I came with cache something.

It's weird! I enter a URL in address bar (think of which uses **SSL** protocol), hit enter, I can see request is being sent to server successfully and with no error shown I can see the content normally.

Some minutes later, I'm going to open that website again but my browser (Google Chrome) throws an error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` so I wonder if it is a browser-related issue. I open another browser, IE if Firefox is not there, try to open that website and get a similar connection error within 10 seconds.

Thanks God my modem has an antenna and I can connect via WiFi. I open my mobile phone browser try to open the same URL, get the same error.

Although it's obviously not about browser cache or DNS cache from Windows, I cleared the first one and flushed the second. I turned off modem and turn it on after. I can't reach the website yet.

So I thought if it could be the modem which is the culprit (I can open that website if I connect through a VPN/Proxy server), I thought if there is some caching in modem which prevents my request to be sent and completed but I'm not sure about it. Guides on this problem are really appreciated.

Comment: Could be your ISP is having DNS issues. Try setting your DNS to `8.8.8.8` (google-public-dns-a.google.com) and 
`208.67.222.222` (resolver1.opendns.com)

Comment: @DavidPostill It got no difference.

Comment: Web caching is not something cheap hardware will do, your ISP might be doing it but not if its HTTPs. First port of call is to ask your ISP to check their logs.

Comment: Does this happen with all sites, or just a specific one?  It could be just the site that's having problems.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like something is closing your TCP connection. You have 3 possible culprits:

- PC
- Modem/Router
- 3rd Party (ISP related)

So to isolate try with a different device. If you get the same issue it is one of the other two. Then try a different modem/router and if you still get the problem change ISP.